# Fix COM reference: The type library importer could not convert the signature for the member DISPPARAMS.rgvarg

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-sdk

I have a build server where I build a Visual Studio extension. I recently migrated to a different server that and now I get the following warnings:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1988,5): warning MSB3305: Processing COM reference "" from path "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\stdole2.tlb". The type library importer could not convert the signature for the member 'DISPPARAMS.rgvarg'.
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1988,5): warning MSB3305: Processing COM reference "" from path "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\stdole2.tlb". The type library importer could not convert the signature for the member 'DISPPARAMS.rgdispidNamedArgs'.

The primary difference between this new server and the previous server is that the previous server had an Isolated Shell installed (the Microsoft Visual Studio Management Studio). I guess I am missing a server registration, but I have no idea which.

Comment: Hi - I'm seeing this too - did you ever find a reason?

Comment: The only way I could solve this issue is by installing Visual Studio on the build machine. You could try and use tlbimp to convert the types in stdole2.tlb.

Comment: Try installing the "Desktop Experience" feature, which includes a number of miscellaneous things.

Answer (score 2):

While not an explanation of the problem, [this link on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7a7c352b-20cb-4931-b3b5-27e899016f75/turning-off-msbuild-warnings-msb3305?forum=msbuild&prof=required) shows how the warning can be suppressed by adding the following item to the PropertyGroup at the top of the .csproj file:

```
<ResolveComReferenceSilent>True</ResolveComReferenceSilent>
```

Comment: I added the specified property group but it doesn't go away for me.

Comment: Turns out I had two projects referencing the same COM object and although it always only produces the two errors you need the property tag in all projects that reference the COM object.